# how to get through this Fatal Error problem?

Tags: php, css

```
**Fatal error: Method Template::__toString() must not throw an exception, caught ParseError: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\joblister\index.php on line 0**
```

i dont know where is the wrong part? can you guys help me? i kept trying but nothing can fix it.

```
<?php include_once 'config/init.php'; ?>
    
    
    <?php
    
    $job = new Job;
    
    $template = new Template('templates/frontpage.php');
    
    $template->title = 'Latest Jobs';
    $template->jobs = $job->getAllJobs();
    
    echo $template;
    
    ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

this is because you are trying to echo an object not string ...

in the template class you either need to implement the magic function __toString() and define how the object should be printed or you may have your custom method in the class for example getHtml() .. which returns the built string and echo it like that

echo $template->getHtml();